# flutter build Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. Thes file were found in the classpath

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile-application, gradle-cache

flutter build Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath

How can I solve this problem running flutter build apk on android studio and getting this error

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3588 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
e: /Users/abay/AndroidStudioProjects/APP/build/pdfx/.transforms/6056d760e9ce853d5cf980b7f88e51b5/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/pdfx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/AndroidStudioProjects/APP/build/package_info_plus/.transforms/0e8caa431af1648e5e1ce72dc456937d/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/AndroidStudioProjects/APP/build/device_info_plus/.transforms/91bb97461a9cca9477daa006d7011bf5/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/device_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/AndroidStudioProjects/APP/build/flutter_jailbreak_detection/.transforms/c388b8af80d72fbdbd43f68c73b0d92f/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/flutter_jailbreak_detection_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/23b7c5d258aa7958f4e9c71936197225/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e72bbe5cd64dafe6e49040dd1a2e0995/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3ff098f73cae984ab260cb5c62c62141/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7f999814d70876ff955aeb78ea31903c/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6ce66bf89cb4bc07dc7c20651fd67eb7/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/feb072e1a249f946f2ed76722b3a2b98/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8695bfff398a0ab82e4aad3da95c3a27/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a0f867253f1f396321b2a295f3b4b200/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.1/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-android/1.7.1/c2d86b569f10b7fc7e28d3f50c0eed97897d77a7/kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/324b7bec833e1da73fc3cda2e7c4c24d/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-java-1.0.0-beta05/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/081afc8534ca4bdd15c695e01b34faeb/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-1.0.0-beta05/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.7.1/63a0779cf668e2a47d13fda7c3b0c4f8dc7762f4/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/1.7.1/6333bad6f256e2ca7bc2908f586be7161a41618c/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a6ab26129953208e7e3f1f6f67ee9bb4/transformed/fragment-1.6.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/fragment_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/32de0e2540e8e025ace4514199b3ea64/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.20/e58b4816ac517e9cc5df1db051120c63d4cde669/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.20/e58b4816ac517e9cc5df1db051120c63d4cde669/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/abay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.20/e58b4816ac517e9cc5df1db051120c63d4cde669/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

app build.grade setting

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64', 'x86'
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
            }
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

android > build.grade

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompiler){
    option.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:deprecation'
}
```

How can I solve this problem This problem occurs every time a FLUTTER build occurs